# Single setting to turn off TypeScript in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

How does one disable all TypeScript intellisense/formatting etc. in VSCode? I know only one way, that is to change the settings for each TypeScript setting...

Is there a single setting to just turn it all off?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a setting but you can go to `Extension Manager` (Ctrl + Shift + X) - `More Actions` (the `'...'` menu) and click `Show Built-in Extensions`. You can also type `@builtin` in the extensions search box.

Then you can disable globally or for the current workspace, either the `Typescript Language Basics` extension (provides snippets, syntax highlighting, bracket matching and folding in TypeScript files) or the `TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features` extension (provides rich language support for JavaScript and TypeScript).